# Is it possible to use a local image in an HTML or CSS project using Javascript or any other means?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The best I can do is:

```
<img width='220' height='280' src='chrome-extension://okjaohhbffepkcfacapapdhkmnebgiba/johnny.jpg' class="me"/>
```

but this will only display the image in Chrome. Is there any way to do this so the image will show in all browsers?

Thanks in advance,
Dzhon

Comment: You could base64 encode the image and include it in the HTML as a data URI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the image as base64 and then call in in using CSS. There's a nice guide here:  https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: You also need a converter if you don't want to write one yourself: http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/